# Nested async.eachSeries stacks iterations

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following function receives an array of links and scans the remote website, gets 10 blog posts per page and  then each comment for blog post, using `async.waterfall`.

```
// @param {Array} url
export default function getData(url, cb) {
  const arrayOfPosts = [];
  // Outer loop
  async.eachSeries(url, (link, topLVLcb) => {

    // Waterfall
    async.waterfall([

      // Collects links to posts
      callback => {
        request(link, (err, response, body) => {
          console.log(`working on ${link}`);

          const $ = cheerio.load(body);

          // OVERALL 10 LINKS PER ONE BLOGPOST
          $('.blogpost').each((i, element) => {

            // build post ojbect

            const post =  {
              content,
              link,
              comments: []
            }
            arrayOfPosts.push(post);
          });
          callback(null, arrayOfPosts);
        });
      },

      // Looks for details in given post
      (arrOfPosts, postDetailsCallback) => {
        let counter = 1;

        // Inner loop through 10 links
        async.eachSeries(arrOfPosts, (post, eachSeriesCallback) => {
          request(post.link, (err, response, body) => {
            console.log(counter++);
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.comment').each((i, element) => {

              // build comment

              const comment = {
                author,
                content
              };

              post.comments.push(comment);
            });
            eachSeriesCallback(null);
          });
        }, postDetailsCallback);
      }
    ], err => {
      console.log('DONE PAGE');
      console.log('*************************');
      topLVLcb(err);
    });
  }, (result, err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log('DONE ALL');
      cb(arrayOfPosts);
    }
  });
}
```

It provides output like this:

```
working on www.mywebsite.com/
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
DONE PAGE
**************************************************************
working on www.mywebsite.com/posts/1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
DONE PAGE
**************************************************************
```

And it increments each page by ten, starting all over again with an each iteration. Whilst it should scan each page 10 times. I think that I've messed some of the callbacks, but I can't figure out for exactly hours already. This is my first nodejs async code and it's very overwhelming.

Comment: That's a mistake at your second line.const arrayOfPosts is global and for each  iteration it grows 0,10,20,30,40,50,....so on!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're storing all posts in the top level `arrayOfPosts` but that means that in your second waterfall function you'll be processing all posts from the beginning since that's what you're passing to the callback. So, in your first callback that collects links to posts you should have a local array of posts that you would pass to the next callback.

Comment: Thank you, it something such minor details confuse you the most.

Answer (score 1):

> the `arrayOfPost[]` is global to every `async.waterfall`... for each
>   url Element in `url` you should create a new `arrayOfPost[]` like as
>   follows....

```
export default function getData(url, cb) {
    const arrayOfPosts = [];
    // Outer loop
    async.eachSeries(url, (link, topLVLcb) => {
        var tmpArr=[];
    // Waterfall
    async.waterfall([

        // Collects links to posts
        callback => {
        request(link, (err, response, body) => {
        console.log(`working on ${link}`);

    const $ = cheerio.load(body);

    // OVERALL 10 LINKS PER ONE BLOGPOST
    $('.blogpost').each((i, element) => {

        // build post ojbect

        const post =  {
            content,
            link,
            comments: []
        }
        tmpArr.push(post);
        arrayOfPosts.push(post);
});
    callback(null, tmpArr);//this tmpArr which is being passed will always cantain 10 items(posts) so there will be 10 iterations for each element in url
});
},

    // Looks for details in given post
    (arrOfPosts, postDetailsCallback) => {
        let counter = 1;

        // Inner loop through 10 links
        async.eachSeries(arrOfPosts, (post, eachSeriesCallback) => {
            request(post.link, (err, response, body) => {
            console.log(counter++);
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.comment').each((i, element) => {

                // build comment

                const comment = {
                    author,
                    content
                };

            post.comments.push(comment);
        });
            eachSeriesCallback(null);
        });
    }, postDetailsCallback);
    }
    ], err => {
        console.log('DONE PAGE');
        console.log('*************************');
        topLVLcb(err);
    });
}, (result, err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log('DONE ALL');
            cb(arrayOfPosts);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this code won't work because the in very bottom  `cb` expect an array to extract from this function.

Comment: Updated Answer check!